# Talend + FreeMarker

Tags: freemarker, talend

Is there any way to use FreeMarker template to generate output in Talend OpenStudio (free version)? I want to read data from RDBMS and invoke FreeMarker Template to generate RDF data.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Talend Open Studio as well as the enterprise version do not have any Freemarker support. You can check [Talend exchange](https://exchange.talend.com) to see if the community provides some custom component, which supports Freemarker templates or some other templating framework.

To solve your problem, you could either write **your own Talend component** (there are various tutorials that teach how to write a component - see links below) or **you can add the Freemarker jar by using the tLibraryLoad component and write some Java code in within the job. For example: You could simply use a tJavaFlex component and receive some data flow.** In the begin part of the tJavaFlex component, you initialize the Freemarker configuration and load the template from String or classpath. In the main part of the component, you collect the data of the incoming flow within a model, using custom logic. Finally In the end part of the tJavaFlex component, you process the template with the help of your model and write it into a file.

http://www.powerupbi.com/talend/componentCreation_1.html
https://help.talend.com/display/KB/How+to+create+a+custom+component